# not getting resource id of images in my code

Tags: android, listview, android-resources, baseadapter

I am trying to make a custom list view with Imageviews in each row that would set their image resource through a string i get from database. The database only contains the name of the images and I need to load it from resources. I've tried all the methods to get resource by name but the function always returns 0. I cannot get my id based on name no matter what I do. This is the Custom adapter that I am using....

public class OwnAddptor extends BaseAdapter {

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
String[] names;
String[] detailarray;
String[] adapimage;
int size;
Context mycont;


public OwnAddptor(Context context,String[] poi_names,String[] details,String[] imageadap) {

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.names = poi_names;
        this.detailarray = details;
        this.adapimage = imageadap;
        this.mycont = context;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return names.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int puhj) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return puhj;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
     ViewHolder holder;

        if (vi == null) {
            vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.blockview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.headline = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.head_line);
            holder.detail = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.detail);
            holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else {  
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();  
        }  
        holder.headline.setText(names[position]);
        holder.detail.setText(detailarray[position]);
       // Drawable imgdraw = mycont.getResources().getDrawable(adapimage[position]);
        holder.image.setImageDrawable(getAndroidDrawable(adapimage[position], mycont));
        System.out.println(adapimage[position]);
        return vi;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView headline;
        TextView detail;
        ImageView  image;
    }
    public int getImageId(Context context, String name) {
        System.out.println("current name"+name);
        return context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/"+name, null, context.getPackageName());



    }
    static public Drawable getAndroidDrawable(String pDrawableName,Context cont){

        int resourceId=Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(pDrawableName, "drawable", cont.getPackageName());
        System.out.println("resource ids****"+resourceId);
        if(resourceId==0){
            return null;
        } else {
            return Resources.getSystem().getDrawable(resourceId);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the main activity where I query the database and pass the array to the custom adapter class. The text views set correctly according to the position. The only problem is in getting the int id of the images from the resource folder.
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
DataBaseHelper baseHelper ;
SQLiteDatabase database;
OwnAddptor adapcustom;
 TextView  detail;
 ListView  view;
 TextView headline;
 String[] name;
 String[] images;
 String[] desc;
 int[] imgids;   
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    List<RowItem> rowItems;

      view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
     baseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        try
        {
         baseHelper.createDatabase(); 
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
           throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }
        try
        {
          baseHelper.openDataBase();

        }
        catch(SQLException sqle)
        {
           throw sqle;
        }
      database = baseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
      Cursor cursor= database.rawQuery("Select * from tblArpoi_local", null);
      int i = 0;

          if (cursor.getCount()>0) {
              cursor.moveToFirst();
              name = new String[cursor.getCount()];
              desc = new String[cursor.getCount()];
              images= new String[cursor.getCount()];
              imgids = new int[cursor.getCount()];
      while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        images[i]= "poi_"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("arPoiImageLink"));
        name[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("arPoiName"));
        desc[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("arPoiDescription"));

                i++;
    }



      System.out.println("****"+images.length);
      database.close();
      cursor.close();
      adapcustom = new OwnAddptor(this,name,desc,images);
      view.setAdapter(adapcustom);




          }
}
 public static int getImageId(Context context, String name) {
        System.out.println("current name"+name);
        return context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/"+name, null, context.getPackageName());

 }
```

}

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the right names from the database?

Comment: int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(pictureName , "drawable", getPackageName()); Does this also return null to you?

Comment: have you tried with the given solution below?

Comment: Yes I've checked the names and they are the same with the drawable folder. I've used all the suggestions but still the id returned is zero. Please if you guys can tell me if there is something wrong with the way I am getting the name of the Image... its like adapImage[position]....I've Logged the output of array and I am getting all the correct names from the array but still it returns ID 0

Comment: @user1900738 if my given solution helps you to solve your problem then you can accept my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this it will solve your problem.

```
ImageView my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_imageView);
my_image.setBackgroundResource(getResId("ic_launcher"));
```

Declare following function to get Drawable Resource Id from the passed drawable string name.

```
public static int getResId(String drawableName) {    
    try {
        Class res = R.drawable.class;
        Field field = res.getField(drawableName);
        int drawableId = field.getInt(null);
        System.out.println("resource ids****"+drawableId);
        return drawableId;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MyTag", "Failure to get drawable id.", e);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

That's It.

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
context.getResources().getIdentifier(drawableResourceName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

and it works like a sharm.

you could try to call

```
holder.image.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getIdentifier(drawableResourceName, "drawable", context.getPackageName()));
```

instead of

```
holder.image.setImageDrawable(getAndroidDrawable(adapimage[position], mycont));
```

hope this help